# iframe + jquery + bind a click function

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I have an iframe that loads by user request so its not available on first page load.

I want to be able to setup event listeners with the following 2 types of code:

```js
$('iframe#joinIframe').contents().find('img#closePopUp').bind('click', function () {
    console.log('iframe baby');
});
```

and

```js
$('iframe#joinIframe img#closePopUp').bind('click', function() {
    console.log('iframe baby');
});
```

however I get no reply.

Is there a way to have an initial page loaded, open an iframe later and bind events to this from the orginal page - I wanted to have some control/functionality from the underlying page.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$(document).on('click', '#joinIframe #closePopUp', function (){
        console.log('iframe baby');
});
```